# Windows Form application could not find axWindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows form applicaiton. In fact is a video player(media player) and buttons play stop pause etc. I have designed everything and it was working smoothly until 1hour ago. From that time I am receiving the following message in the form design . The message depicted in the following image:
[image]

How can I overcome that issue?

In the designer script I am having:

```
private AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWindowsMediaPlayer1;
```

My issue began when I tried to create a second form in the same project. When I deleted the second form suddenly I got that message in my first form.

Comment: Check the designer class and whether variable is there

Comment: It is defined normally in the designer private AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWindowsMediaPlayer1;

Comment: Some code might be useful as well as the error details from the output window. The call stack would help as well. but sounds like It can't find the assembly that you referenced. I assume its a 3rd party lib. I cant comment on this site yet so this isnt really an answer.

Comment: You can close the designer and try to clean/rebuild the solution. Or as a last resort, open the `Form1.Designer.cs` file, find all instances of the media player control and delete them. Close and reopen the designer. You'll have to add your media player control again but the code-behind should still work since it should give it the same name.

Comment: Have you tried removing the Windows Media Player control from your project and the .interop that's likely to have been created by .NET in either your debug or release folder. You could clean the solution if that's easier, then re-add the Windows Media Player control to it. This will re-create the axWindowsMediaPlayer1. Based on the error above, check that you're compiling with the right platform i.e. Any CPU. If that doesn't work, try x86. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried every combination release/debug and x86/x64 nothing solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried remove the assembly `AxWMPLib` from your **Reference** folder and add it back again?

It clearly says at the top:

> Could not find type AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer. Please make sure that the assembly that contains that type is referenced.

Then, make sure that the correct `using` is located in the file. It should be added automatically but if it's missing, check to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer fixed your issue, please mark it as "Answered" so that the next user knows what fixed your specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, after I upgraded VS 2019 to 2022.

My project was built in 2019. What I had done was I closed the main project and opened a new project, then I added *Windows Media Player* to the project.

That went ahead normally.

I then closed the project and opened a previously loaded project and it worked fine, under VS 2019. (I did this without closing VS' main window. I closed projects using the File menu.)